# I want an implit loading spinner to be displayed in a fragment which has some views and the user clicks any one of them

Tags: android-fragments, android-recyclerview, loading

I have a fragment which basically has a recyclerView.  So when the user clicks on any item of the view, the background needs to change (the item clicked needs to be highlighted) and a loading spinner needs to appear and then fragment needs to replaced based on the item clicked. How to achieve this? In the below code, I have implemented the highlight facility, but once an item is clicked redirection should happen....

My Internal Layout, (layout_research)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/loginCardRadius"
android:elevation="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"
android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/loginViewsMargin">

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="@string/abc"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/loginViewsMargin"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="2"/>

       </LinearLayout>
       </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

My External Layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:weightSum="12"
            android:background="@drawable/login_shape_bk"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_login_bk" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/abcd"/>

            <include
                layout="@layout/internal_research"/>

        </LinearLayout>

     </RelativeLayout>

     </ScrollView>

     </RelativeLayout>
```

My Java File,

```
      package com.example.a123;

       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.widget.ImageView;
       import android.widget.TextView;

       import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
       import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
       import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
       import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

      import java.util.ArrayList;

        public class research extends Fragment {
         int selectedPosition=-1;
             private String[] names = {"Blogs & Books","Patents","Projects","Publications"};
               private int[] image ={R.drawable.books,R.drawable.patents,R.drawable.project,R.drawable.publications};
                 private ArrayList<adapter_for_research> mProfiles;
              private RecyclerView mProfileRecyclerView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mProfiles = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i =0;i<names.length;i++){
        adapter_for_research s = new adapter_for_research();
        s.setname(names[i]);
        s.setImageId(image[i]);
        mProfiles.add(s);
    }
    setRetainInstance(true);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_research, container, false);
    mProfileRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

        updateUI();
        return view;
}

private void updateUI(){
    ProfileAdapter mAdapter = new ProfileAdapter(mProfiles);
    mProfileRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

private class ProfileHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private adapter_for_research mProfilecsg;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private TextView mnameTextView;

    private ProfileHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mnameTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    }

    private void bindData(adapter_for_research s){
        mProfilecsg = s;
        mImageView.setImageResource(s.getImageId());
        mnameTextView.setText(s.getname());
    }
}

private class ProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileHolder>{
    private ArrayList<adapter_for_research> mProfiles;
    private ProfileAdapter(ArrayList<adapter_for_research> profile){
        mProfiles = profile;
    }
    @NonNull
    public ProfileHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item,parent,false);
        return new ProfileHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ProfileHolder holder, final int position) {
        adapter_for_research s = mProfiles.get(position);
        holder.bindData(s);
        if(selectedPosition==position)
            holder.itemView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.item_select));
        else
            holder.itemView.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),R.drawable.item_nselect));

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                selectedPosition=position;
                notifyItemChanged(selectedPosition);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mProfiles.size();
    }
}
 }
```

Adapter Class,

```
     package com.example.a123;


       class adapter_for_research {
         private String mName;
         private int mImageId;
        String getname() {
            return mName;
        }
       void setname(String mName) {
             this.mName = mName;
          }
         int getImageId() {
           return mImageId;
         }
          void setImageId(int mImageId) {
          this.mImageId = mImageId;
         }
      }
```

Comment: Please add your source codes with the questions. How did you implemented your recyclerview. With a ViewHolder?

Comment: I think you should implement your background changes and alert dialogs on the holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(). Should work.

Comment: Can you please elaborate and explain brother?

Comment: I don't have android studio to run and check this now. But lets say you are going to change the background color of your selected item, you can use holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rowitem_layout... relativelayout_id..setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.WHITE));
            }
        });

Comment: Background colour is changing bro, now I need the fragment transaction to take place after an implit loading spinner appears, and in this process the user shouldn't be able to click some other item(closable=false I beleive) and then when user clicks back on the new fragment he should come back to this fragment...

Comment: Have you checked bro?

Comment: Ohhh i'm sorry I couldn't. But I'll give you my opinion. You have to load the dialog on the holder.itemview.setOnClickListenser() and make your fragment transactions on the spinner item selectedlistner. If you have to do it with a specific value get a text id from your selected recyclerview item and make your fragment transactions based on that item.

Comment: I got the idea, but how to do it, could you please elaborate?

Comment: Have you implement your code snippet for the spinner dialog?

Comment: No, I am unable to figure out the way to write it